# plone.app.caching and settings Varnish to purge the cache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plone, varnish, purge

I am running Plone 4.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. How one should configure

- Varnish (public IP:80) - default.vcl from Ubuntu/Debian
- plone.app.caching

... so that purging works correctly

I am not that interest getting per-page cache clears, but having Purge button working in the site control panel would be nice and giving editors to easy to clear the cache in the case of emergency.

(Alternative I can show how to use varnishadm, but I think setting up Varnish and Plone to discuss each other cannot be that difficult)

Answer (score 1):

What have you filled in the caching control panel?

One oddity is that you need to always add the port to the domain, so something like http://example.com:80 (the docs are fixed in SVN) if you want to accept multiple domains.

If you run Varnish on port 80, it should be clear that virtual host rewriting doesn't happen in front of Varnish, so you set the corresponding checkbox accordingly.